# Login with facebook in IONIC with ngOpenFb

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, ionic-framework, openfb

I don't know he oauth works in detail, but I know the overview.
So I have ionic app running in localhost (ionic serve) and a facebook created.
I have not put any callback url in advanced settings of fb app.
And I am using [ngOpenFb](https://github.com/r-wettstaedt/ngOpenFB) to accomplish login with facebook.
On click of button I am calling a function which will open facebook in new window, on logging in successfully it will redirect to http://localhost:8100/oauthcallback.html.
What should be done next? Do i need to specify some redirect in oauthcallback.html?
Please help..